# Django - one-to-one modelAdmin

Tags: django, one-to-one

I am moderately proficient with django and trying to use model forms for an intranet project.

Essentially, I have a "Resources" model, which is populated by another team.
Second model is "Intake", where users submit request for a resource. It has one-to-one mapping to resource.

Objective is to only allow 1 resource allocation per intake.

Now, Intake model form shows the form, with a drop-down field to resource, with a caveat that it shows all resources, regardless of previous allocation or not.

ex. if resource is taken by an intake, save button detects that disallow saves. This is expected, but then the drop-down should not show that resource in the first place.

How can I do this, i.e. do not show resource already allocated ?

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Resource Pool"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Intake(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    requestor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', default=1)
    resource = models.OneToOneField(Resource, verbose_name="Allocation")
    project = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Environment Request"

    def __str__(self):
        print("self called")
        return self.project
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom form in your admin and change the queryset value of the `resource` field. Something like this:

**admin.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models import Q

from .models import Intake

class IntakeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IntakeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['resource'].queryset = Resource.objects.filter(
            Q(intake__isnull=True) | Q(intake=self.instance)
        )

class IntakeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = IntakeForm

admin.site.register(Intake, IntakeAdmin)
```

Comment: @user1619524 Glad it worked. It would be great if you could mark it as an answer though. :)

Comment: Yes, I did, sorry for a minute delay as I got excited to see it work and got distracted with the docs. Good day to you.

Comment: Thanks. This works well. Just one comment that to perform the reverse relational queries, in `Intake` we should specify a `related_name`: resource = models.OneToOneField(Resource, verbose_name="Allocation", related_name="intake"). Otherwise Django would complain.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use `limit_choices_to` on the field definition:

```
resource = models.OneToOneField(Resource, verbose_name="Allocation",
                                limit_choices_to={'intake__isnull': True})
```

Comment: Yes, it works for the NEW view of Intake modelAdmin, I can see only un-allocated resources. Thanks for this. 

HOWEVER, when I go to the "change" view of Intakes and edit an existing item, it does not show the associated resource, rather it shows the unallocated resource list for selection. Edit view should show the previously selected resource instead. Please can you help me here, my best regards.

Comment: Essentially, limit_choices_to functionality should be applied on "add" pages and not to "change" pages. Appreciate any hints on how to do this :)