# Django: OneToOne dropdown in the admin interface and unique associations

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Referring to [Django - one-to-one modelAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43940563/1504082) i am still searching for a solution to my problem with the admin interface of Django and my OneToOne relationship.

I have the following model which extends the standard User model with an additional attribute `is_thing_staff`:

```
class ThingStaff(models.Model):
    """ Extends the django user model by a separate model relationship which holds additional user
    attributes
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # by default a new user is not a staff member which take care of the thing administration
    is_thing_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return u"{}".format(self.user.username)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Thing Staff"
        verbose_name_plural = "Thing Staff"
```

If i create a new ThingStaff object in the django admin interface, i can select all users, even if there is already a relationship for a user. Saving a new object with a duplicate association to a user results in an error, that there is already an ThingStaff object associated with that User. So far this is more or less ok.

But why show up possible selections if they would result in an error in the next step? So i excluded them via

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ThingStaff

class ThingStaffForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ThingStaffForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(
           id__in=ThingStaff.objects.values_list('user_id', flat=True)
        )

@admin.register(ThingStaff)
class ThingStaffAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ThingStaffForm
```

Great so far: The already associated users will not show up in the dropdown during the creation of a new ThingStaff object.

But if i want to change an existing association, the related user will also not show up in the dropdown which makes it impossible to reset the `is_thing_staff` flag.

So my question is: How can i enable this specific user again for the change view in the django admin interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your exclution list must be updated and selected user for this ThingStaff must not excluded

update your form like this

```
class ThingStaffForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ThingStaffForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    exclude_user = ThingStaff.objects.all()
    if self.instance:
         exclude_user = exclude_user.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
    self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(id__in=exclude_user.values('user_id'))
```

this code check if current form is edit form and have an instance exclude that from exclude list.

Answer (score 2):

Django's `ModelForm` distinguishes between add and change views (each one has it's on own method). This means that you can override it:

```
class ThingStaffAdmin(ModelAdmin):
     def add_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.form = ThingStaffAddForm
         return super().add_view(*args, **kwargs)

     def change_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.form = ThingStaffChangeForm
         return super().change_view(*args, **kwargs)
```

More in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

Comment: Thanks for the information. I choose the answer of @vorujack as i only need one method for all of it. But using the _view methods is more self documenting what the code achieves.